# How do I find the easter egg characters in Gemini Rue?

Tags: gemini-rue

I found Ed from Cowboy Bebop on my first playthrough, but I don't know what actions triggered the event.
How can I get the rest of easter egg characters? And also do I have to find them in the same playthrough to get the Steam achievement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found them all, they are the main characters from Cowboy Bebop:

- Spike: When you get into Matthius apartment, after the Boryokudan
  members leave and before checking the terminal return to the first
  screen.
- Jet: When you can change between characters, go to Hibiscus
  Highrise and he is in the second to last level of stairs.
- Faye: After curing Paul Erickson, return to the burned down hideout where you
  obtained the Carbon Ray Stabilizer.
- Ed/Ein: As soon as you can get in
  the appartment building where Paul Erickson lives, go to the top
  floor and you will find Ed next to the window.

And you need to find them in the same playthrough to get the achievement.

And... bonus!