# How do I get all the achievements in Gemini Rue?

Tags: gemini-rue

I know about [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37417), but there are several other achievements that you can beat the game without getting

- **Collect all 4 hidden notes in Center 7** - I only found 2
- **Find all three extra ammo cases** - I never found *any*!
- **Help your fellow man** - ???

Are there any others?  How do you get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: [Guide on Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=186363144)

**Mementos** 
Find the 6 hidden notes in Center 7.

The second of two collectible "side-quests" in Gemini Rue, this is Delta-Six's counterpart to Azrial's magazines; as with Scavenger, it becomes available as soon as the player is allowed to switch between characters.

While the achievement description mentions six notes, two of them are acquired automatically by progressing through the story - the remaining four are scattered in the various locations of Center 7.

- The first one can be acquired inside either of the elevators of Center 7 - it should be visible on the floor to the left of the elevator entrance.
  [image]
- The second is wedged underneath an impassable door in the [Testing Facility - Blue Corridor] area (the one Delta-Six needs to enter to complete his gun training) - it should be visible as soon as you reach the end of the corridor. Note that you'll need to head to the [Mess Hall] first for the [Blue Corridor] area to become accessible.
  [image]
- The third one is also wedged under a door, this time in the [Gym Facility] floor (where Balder hangs out) - it should be visible to the left of the screen as soon as you exit the elevator.
  [image]
- The final note only appears once you've completed Delta-Six's advanced gun training (see also: "Grade A Student" achievement) and entering the elevator with Epsilon-Five. It should appear in the same elevator that the first note was at; if not, check the other elevator as well.
  [image]

**Scavenger** 
Find all 3 extra ammo magazines.

**Location**: (Azriel) New Pittsburgh - Streets 
One of two collectible "side-quests" in Gemini Rue, this one is available as soon as you acquire the ability to switch between characters. There are three extra magazines for Azriel's pistol located in the various [Streets] locations in New Pittsburgh.

- The first is located in the [Trash Heaps] area, one screen to the left of where the game begins (where Azriel acquires the [ID Card] from the dead Boryokudan goon). As soon as you climb down to the trash, you should be able to see it to the right of your character's sprite.
  [image]
- The second is located underneath a dumpster in the [T-Junction] location, one screen to the right of the shop (where Azriel exits from the [Back Alley] during the first escape sequence). It's visible at the foot of the dumpster on the left side of the road.
  [image]
- The final one is located inside the clogged drain in front of the [Boryokudan HQ] building (the same drain that contains the WT2 [Security Card] Sayuri asks for). After kicking the filth once for the [Security Card], kick it another three times and the magazine should appear.
  [image]

**Good Samaritan** 
Heal the fellow Man on Barracus.

**Location**: (Azriel) New Pittsburgh - Streets 
Awarded for using the [Juice Withdrawal Medicine] you acquired at the [Hibiscus Highrise] building on the homeless man outside the [Back Alley]. Note that you need to do this before administering said medicine to Paul Erickson, as the item disappears from your inventory afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try consulting [this guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=186363144) on steam

Comment: Maybe re-iterate at least the main points, in case that page is removed at some point?